# Can't pass variable value from one function to another

Tags: python, boto3

I'm new to Python and tried similar suggestions from here and failed.

I'm writing a script that consists of few functions, the first function will create some of the variables that will be used in other functions (it can't global variables).
When I've tried my script I kept getting NameError for undefined vars.

```
import boto3
import json
from awsretry import AWSRetry
from botocore.exceptions import ClientError

@AWSRetry.backoff(tries=5)

def instance_details(event, context):    
    client = boto3.client('ec2')]
    ec2_resource = boto3.resource('ec2')`
    alert = event['Records'][0]['Sns']['Message']
    instance_id = alert['Trigger']['Dimensions'][0]['value']
    instance = ec2_resource.Instance(instance_id)
    return client 

@AWSRetry.backoff(tries=5)

def tagging():
    instance_type = instance['Reservations'][0]['Instances'][0]['InstanceType']
```

Why I can't pass the values of `instance` and `client` to other functions?

Thanks in advance and sorry for duplicates.

Comment: change return in instance details to, return {"client": client, "instance": instance}, and while invoking tagging, use the return values

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`intance_details` i believe is lambda handler method. Since you are returing client I believe you should be able to see client value in the variable in which you will be capturing return of this method.

Apart from that, you can try to use Class here and declare these variables in `__init__` method. Then create instance of that class in the lambda handler and access these variables. Then you would be able to use these variables in the whole class.

```
import boto3
class Answer:
    def __init__(self):
        self.instance = None
        self.client = boto3.client('ec2')]
        self.ec2_resource = boto3.resource('ec2')

    def meth1(self):
        # suppose here we want to use the value of instance
        # using self.instance you can use the value of instance here
        # you can pass the alert from lambda_handler to this method 
        # as well and do all the computation here too.
        print(self.client) # example how to use class variables.

def lambda_handler(event, context):
    ans = Answer()
    alert = event['Records'][0]['Sns']['Message']
    instance_id = alert['Trigger']['Dimensions'][0]['value']
    ans.instance = ans.ec2_resource.Instance(instance_id)
    # if you want to pass instance id, you can pass in the arguments and
    # change the definition of meth1 accordingly.
    # Apart form that you can pass the alert in the meth1 too and do all the computation there.
    ans.meth1()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    lambda_handler(event, "")
```

Comment: Thanks, I'm quite a noob... First script ever..
Care to show\explain how\what exactly I need?
Thanks!

Comment: @TomerLeibovich I have added the code in the answer.